# Custom DOCKER_HOST in Elastic Beanstalk Docker environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ElasticBeanstalk setup using Amazon's Docker AMI. I have just started experimenting with setting up a new environment within my EB Application. It is running as Webserver with Docker.

What I am trying to do with this environment is have Docker daemon running that is running on TCP rather than a Unix socket. That works by modifying `/etc/sysconf/docker` and adding the `-H` flag. Unfortunately, that breaks that EB deployment scripts because they are expecting the Docker daemon on the default Unix socket.

I have tried to add a `/etc/profile/docker.sh` which contains the appropriate `DOCKER_HOST` variable. However, it doesn't seem to be picked up by the EB deployment scripts.

Did anyone try something similar? Where can I 'globally' set the `DOCKER_HOST` so it gets picked up by the EB deployment?

I appreciate any hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use multiple `-H` flags](https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/#bind-docker-to-another-hostport-or-a-unix-socket) to have your docker daemon listening on both the unix socket and TCP socket.

Wouldn't that please the EB deployment script while still allowing you to control the docker daemon with TCP?